# Apache Spark Streaming from folder (not HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was wondering if there is any reliable way for creating spark streams from a physical location? I was using 'textFileStream' but seems it is mainly used if the files are in HDFS. If you see the definition of the function it says "Create an input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you implying that HDFS is not a physical location? There are datanode directories that physically exist...

You should be able to use textFile with the `file://` URI, but you need to ensure all nodes in the cluster can read from that location.

From the definition of Hadoop compatible filesystem.

> The selection of which filesystem to use comes from the URI scheme used to refer to it -the prefix hdfs: on any file path means that it refers to an HDFS filesystem; file: to the local filesystem, s3: to Amazon S3, ftp: FTP, swift: OpenStackSwift, ...etc.
>
> There are other filesystems that provide explicit integration with Hadoop through the relevant Java JAR files, native binaries and configuration parameters needed to add a new schema to Hadoop

Comment: Sorry I meant physical location by UNIX/WINDOWS file system.I was trying to replicate it in Windows with local cores but seems there are some issue where it's only able to read when you change file and then move the files when the spark jobs are running.

Comment: Yes, Spark streaming docs say "The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory". Meaning, existing files are not read. Appending to files won't work

Comment: @Satyabrat Has this answered your question?